# Cannot find method getComponent()

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to implement [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html) JSF page with pagination and sorting. Unfortunately Netbeans shows me error when `getComponent()` is used:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getComponent()
  location: variable event of type java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

I tried to import the dependency  java.awt.event.ActionEvent but there is no change. This is the code where `getComponent()` is used.

```
public void page(ActionEvent event) {
        page(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }
```

What dependencies are needed in order to use `getComponent()`? Can I replace the this Java method with similar method?

Best wishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You imported wrong `ActionEvent`, You need to import

```
javax.faces.event.ActionEvent
```

See [here](http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/myfaces-api/apidocs/javax/faces/event/ActionEvent.html)